# Voice Recognition in node.js

Tags: node.js, voice-recognition

Is it possible, to have voice recognition in node.js, with a free library?

Comment: Speech recognition requires large training models. You likely will not find any library that does this. What you are looking for is an API. You connect to an API by connecting to various "endpoints" (a website for computer code). For example, you can use Google's Speech-To-Text here https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text or AssemplyAI here https://www.assemblyai.com/

I suggest you read on how to connect to an API in node and then search for what speech recognition service suites your needs best.

Comment: Exist voice-recognition https://www.npmjs.com/package/voice-recognition, it's free, without cloud and offline. I try to use it, but no success yet. (It must be compiled)

Comment: Have a go at this, https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-to-voice-authentication-using-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Mozilla offers the DeepSpeech library and model which can be used to transcribe speech to text. From there you can extract keywords.

However, in my own experience this task is better suited to Python simply due to there being more tools in that ecosystem devoted to speech recognition.

Here are some related links that might help you:

- https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/r0.9/USING.html#getting-the-pre-trained-model
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepspeech
- https://dev.to/picovoice/day1-no-code-offline-voice-assistant-m3o
- https://alphacephei.com/vosk/